# Event not emitting inside derived class of event emitter in Node Js

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

**tinyscrapper.js**
I am emitting scrapeStarted event in scrap function

```
const EventEmitter = require("events");
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const { exit } = require("process");


class TinyScraper extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(url, timeout) {
    super();
  this.scrap(url,timeout)  }
  async scrap(url, timeout) {
    this.emit("scrapeStarted");

    let results=null;
    try {
      setTimeout(
        () => {
          console.log("timeout");
          if (!results) {
            this.emit("timeout");
            exit(1)
          }
        },
        timeout
      );
      const { data } = await axios.get(url);
      // Load HTML we fetched in the previous line
      const $ = cheerio.load(data);
      
      const title = $('meta[property="og:title"]').attr("content");
      const image = $('meta[property="og:image"]').attr("content");
      const desc = $('meta[property="og:description"]').attr("content");
      results={ title: title,
        image: `strong text`image,
        description:desc}
      this.emit("scrapeSuccess", results);
      
    } catch (err) {

      this.emit("error", err);
    }
  }
}
module.exports = TinyScraper;
```

I am listening scrapeStarted event in index.js but the event does not listen while it is called in TinyScrapper class. An exciting thing is an error, timeout and scrapeSuccess event is working fine

**Index.js**

// index.js

```
const TinyScraper = require('./tiny-scraper');
const scraper = new TinyScraper('http://localhost:8000/url1',20000);

scraper.on('scrapeSuccess', (data) => {
    console.log('JSON Data received scrapping:', data);
});

scraper.on('scrapeStarted', (data) => {
    console.log('Started Scraping:', data);
});


scraper.on('error', () => {
    console.log('The URL is not valid.');
});


scraper.on('timeout', () => {
    console.log('Scraping timed out');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scraper starts scraping **before** you've registered event listeners. You'll need to register event listeners and then call `scrap` yourself.

```js
class TinyScraper extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(url, timeout) {
    this.url = url;
    this.timeout = timeout
    super();
  }

  async scrape() {
    const {url, timeout} = this;
    this.emit("scrapeStarted");
    // ... rest of method
  }
}
```

And then your `index.js` needs to be refactored to

```js
const TinyScraper = require('./tiny-scraper');
const scraper = new TinyScraper('http://localhost:8000/url1',20000);

scraper.on('scrapeSuccess', (data) => {
    console.log('JSON Data received scrapping:', data);
});

// other .on handlers

scraper.scrape();
```

Comment: Thanks sometimes i act like a big fool

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```js
const EventEmitter = require("events")
const axios = require("axios")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")
const { exit } = require("process")

class TinyScraper extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(url, timeout) {
    super()
    this.scrape(url, timeout)
  }
  async scrape(url, timeout) {
    let result = null
    try {
      process.nextTick(() => {
        this.emit("scrapeStarted", url)
      })
      if (typeof timeout !== 'undefined') {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!result) {
            this.emit("timeout")
            exit(1)
          }
        }, timeout)
      }
      const { data } = await axios.get(url)
      const $ = cheerio.load(data)
      let metaData = {}
      $('meta').each((index, element) => {
        const property = $(element).attr('property')
        const content = $(element).attr('content')
        if (property && content) {
          const propertyName = property.replace(/^og:/, '')
          metaData[propertyName] = content
        }
      })
      result = metaData
      this.emit('scrapeSuccess', result)
    } catch (error) {
      this.emit("error")
    }
  }
}

module.exports = TinyScraper
```

```js
// index.js
const TinyScraper = require('./tiny-scraper');
const scraper = new TinyScraper('http://localhost:8000/url2', 1000);

scraper.on('scrapeSuccess', (data) => {
    console.log('JSON Data received:', data);
});

scraper.on('scrapeStarted', (data) => {
    console.log('Started Scraping:', data);
});


scraper.on('error', () => {
    console.log('The URL is not valid.');
});


scraper.on('timeout', () => {
    console.log('Scraping timed out');
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.